# double click WPF event shortcut for deleting auto generated function and XAML added tags

Tags: wpf, function, shortcut, auto-generate

When I double click on my User Control file, system auto generates a UserControl_Loaded function in .cs file and adds loaded tag in XAML as Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" for UserControl element. It also defines an eventHandler to this.Any shortcut in VS to undo this operation quickly?

Comment: Very wierd, I tried and double clicked everywhere but I didn't get Loaded event implemented. Could you show me where exactly did you double click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just Undo once in the .xaml.cs and then flip back to the .xaml and Undo once there and you'll be back to the initial state. Quick keyboard sequence is `Ctrl-Z`, `Ctrl-Tab`, `Ctrl-Z`.

Comment: Yes John,this is a very simple solution for this operation.could you please help me out with:                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706179/wpf-user-control-in-winforms-project-structuring                        (Thanks in advance :))